# In Sqlite, LIKE function is not working or return nothing

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I use below code to get number from database from given number, for that I fired below query to get number but it does not return number. Is there wrong something in my query? please help me to resolved this issue.

I need to use **LIKE** function because some number stored with special char and whitespace.

```
contactNumber = contactNumber.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]", "");
        contactNumber="%"+contactNumber+"%";
        String strEmail = "";
        String name = "";


Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?", new String[]{contactNumber}, null);
```

Comment: Try using `"'%"+contactNumber+"%'"`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to use LIKE when using ContentProviders:

```
getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + contactNumber + "%" }, null);
```

However, the best way to search by phone number is to use the dedicated [`PhoneLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup) API:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.CONTACT_ID, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
```

It's both optimised to return a result faster, and handles phone numbers with or without country-codes.